# AngularJS Controller not working with simple initialization code

Tags: angularjs

New to AngularJS and no idea wats happening here and nothing is getting populated in  when I run this....

Using version - 1.6 
please have a look, might be very silly problem but not getting through ;)

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div data-ng-controller="simpleController">
  Name:
  <br/>
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="fname" />
  <br/>
  <ul>
   <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name | orderBy:'city'">{{ cust.name | uppercase }} - {{ cust.city | lowercase}}</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function simpleController($scope){
  
  $scope.customers = [
                      {name:'anil', city:'bengaluru'},
                      {name:'rahul', city:'pune'},
                      {name:'abc', city:'hyd'},
                      {name:'xyz', city:'mysore'}
                      ];
 }
```

Comment: can you please have more research on creating angular app module and controllers.
[Angular JS](https://angularjs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Create controller from `angular` then use it

code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="app">

<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-ng-controller="simpleController">
        Name:
        <br/>
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="fname" />
        <br/>
        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name | orderBy:'city'">{{ cust.name | uppercase }} - {{ cust.city | lowercase}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    angular.module("app").controller('simpleController', simpleController);

    function simpleController($scope) {

        $scope.customers = [{
            name: 'anil',
            city: 'bengaluru'
        }, {
            name: 'rahul',
            city: 'pune'
        }, {
            name: 'abc',
            city: 'hyd'
        }, {
            name: 'xyz',
            city: 'mysore'
        }];
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a controller before using it.
Create Controller by:

```
angular.Module("ModuleName",[]).Controller("ControllerName",function($scope){
});
```

According to your code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="app">

<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script>
    angular.module("app",[]).controller('simpleController',

    function simpleController($scope) {

        $scope.customers = [{
            name: 'anil',
            city: 'bengaluru'
        }, {
            name: 'rahul',
            city: 'pune'
        }, {
            name: 'abc',
            city: 'hyd'
        }, {
            name: 'xyz',
            city: 'mysore'
        }];
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-ng-controller="simpleController">
        Name:
        <br/>
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="fname" />
        <br/>
        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name | orderBy:'city'">{{ cust.name | uppercase }} - {{ cust.city | lowercase}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
   
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

1st you need to have a module defined to start your project .[Try this blog to learn more](https://www.toptal.com/angular-js/a-step-by-step-guide-to-your-first-angularjs-app) .  For a simpler example try [this](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_application.asp).

To make your app work you need to   enclose your view with `ng-app` in your case you have that . Then you need to create a `module` in your case its missing . Then add `services` and `controller` according to your need.

```js
 angular.module("app",[])
  .controller("ctrl",simpleController);
 
  function simpleController($scope){
  
  $scope.customers = [
                     {name:'anil', city:'bengaluru'},
                     {name:'rahul', city:'pune'},
                     {name:'abc', city:'hyd'},
                     {name:'xyz', city:'mysore'}
                     ];
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="simpleController">
  Name:
  <br/>
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="fname" />
  <br/>
  <ul>
   <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name | orderBy:'city'">{{ cust.name | uppercase }} - {{ cust.city | lowercase}}</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```